# HTML форматирования для textview через string

Tags: android, html, строки, textview, форматирование

Добрый вечер!
У меня есть `textview` и я вынимаю из `string` в этот `View` элемент текст.

Вынимаю так:

```
MyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.txt_0)))
```

В `string` текст находится между

```
<string name="txt_0"><![CDATA[
```

и

```
]]></string>
```

И вроде бы все хорошо:

```
 <b>, <i>, <u>, <H2>, <br>, &nbsp
```

И другие HTML теги работают. Но, например, мне нужно создать маркированный список:

```
<ul>
  <li>элемент маркированного списка</li>
</ul>
```

Но не работает. Или нужно поставить линию-разделитель,

```
<hr>
```

но снова ничего.

```
<center>
```

Также не работает. Как узнать что работает, а что нет? И как создать список, линию-разделитель? Данный текст вместе с форматированием будет в БД SQLite и вытаскиваться оттуда.

Comment: Вот тут можете посмотреть класс, расширяющий TagHandler с поддержкой `strike/s`, `ul/ol/li` (включая вложенные) и `code` [тык](https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/kuchanov/tproger/utils/html/MyHtmlTagHandler.java)

Comment: Подчеркнул импорт. Не нашел библиотеки:
import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.AttributeGetter;

Comment: Это росто мой вспомогательный класс. Вы можете его заменить на `ContextCompat.getColor()`

Comment: Обращаться:
mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.selected_item),
                null, new MyHtmlTagHandler())); ?

Comment: Да, вроде, всё верно

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что далеко не все HTML теги поддерживаются. Вот список поддерживаемых тегов:

```
<a> (supports attribute "href")
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div>
<em>
<font> (supports attributes "color" and "face")
<i>
<img> (supports attribute "src". Note: you have to include an ImageGetter to handle retrieving a Drawable for this tag)
<p>
<small>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Если вам нужно больше тегов, вам придется делать их поддержку самому, или использовать `WebView` вместо `TextView`

Comment: <blockquote> - линия разделитель вместо <hr>. Но работает неправильно. Линия идет не горизонтальная, а вертикальная рядом с текстом, который входит в этот тег. И синяя, хотя цвет не определялся нигде.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае `<ul>` и `<li>` просто размечают текст, а обрабатывать их нужно уже в коде. Для этого есть интерфейс `Html.TagHandler`, который нужно реализовать. Например, для списка:

```
public class TagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag,
                          Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
        if (!opening && tag.equals("ul")) {
            output.append("\n");
        }
        if (opening && tag.equals("li")) {
            output.append("\n\u2022");
        }
    }
}
```

Осталось вызвать:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.text),
        null, new TagHandler()));
```

Документация по Html в TextView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html